# Allow interrupt in smooth "Scroll to Top" link

Tags: jquery, scroll, interrupt, scrolltop, autoscroll

I'm currently working on a private server, or else I'd share the link to the page I'm working on. Basically, I'm using a smooth "scroll to top" jQuery plugin that displays a button after the user scrolls to a certain point. Clicking that button will smoothly scroll the user back to the top of the page.

The issue is that if a user begins to scroll down during this smooth auto-scroll, the page jumps back and forth between smoothly scrolling to the top and the user trying to scroll down. It ultimately continues this until the page successfully reaches the top of the page, then allowing the user to scroll.

I'd like to implement some sort of interrupt, so that a user can stop the auto-scroll by beginning to scroll manually.